# How to calculate $ \int_0^1 \frac{(1+x)^{2r-1}}{1+x^2}dx $?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, closed-form

Is there a way to express
$$
\int_{0}^{1}{\left(\, 1 + x\,\right)^{2r\ -\ 1} \over \!\!\!\!\!\!\! 1 + x^{2}}
\,{\rm d}x
$$
in a closed form with $r\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: for what stands $r$ here?

Comment: If you consider the incomplete beta function to be a closed form, there is one: $$\frac{1}{4r}\left\{4^r+(1+i) 2^r e^{-\frac{3}{2}  i \pi  r} r \left[-B_{1-i}(-2 r,2r+1)+B_{-i}(-2 r,2 r+1)\\-i e^{3 i \pi  r} (B_i(-2 r,2 r+1)-B_{1+i}(-2 r,2r+1))\right]-1\right\}. $$ Here $B_z(a,b)$ is the incomplete beta function $\int_0^z dt t^{a-1} (1-t)^{b-1}$

Comment: Try and obtain a recurrence relation using successive integration by parts.

Comment: Using the binomial theorem $$I=\sum_{k=0}^{2r-1}{2r-1\choose k}\int_0^1 \frac{x^k}{1+x^2}dx.$$ Taking $k$ even and odd separately gives "nice" values, although I don't have time to work out their closed forms right now.

What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Using the binomial theorem, $$I=\sum_{k=0}^{2r-1}{2r-1\choose k}\int_0^1 \frac{x^k}{1+x^2}dx\equiv \sum_{k=0}^{2r-1}{2r-1\choose k}c_k.$$

When $k\geq 0$ is even (using [A007509](http://oeis.org/A007509)), $$c_k=\frac{\pi}{4} (-1)^{k/2}-(-1)^{k/2} \sum _{\ell=0}^{\frac{k}{2}-1} \frac{(-1)^\ell}{2 \ell+1},$$ and when $k$ is odd (taking an educated guess from the previous sequence), $$c_k=\frac{1}{2} (-1)^{\frac{k-1}{2}} \log (2)+(-1)^{\frac{k-1}{2}} \sum _{\ell=1}^{\frac{k}{2}} \frac{(-1)^\ell}{2 \ell}.$$

Substituting we obtain
$$I = \frac{\pi}{4}\sum_{k=0}^r(-1)^k{2r-1\choose 2k} - \sum_{k=1}^r(-1)^k{2r-1\choose 2k}\sum _{\ell=0}^{k-1} \frac{(-1)^\ell}{2 \ell+1} - \frac{\log 2}{2}\sum_{k=1}^r(-1)^k {2r-1\choose 2k-1} - \sum_{k=1}^r(-1)^k {2r-1\choose 2k-1}\sum _{\ell=1}^{k-1} \frac{(-1)^\ell}{2 \ell}.$$

The first and third summations, combined with the $\ell=0$ summation, have closed form, giving

$$I=\frac{1}{8} \left(2^r (\pi -4+\log (4)) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  r}{2}\right)+2^r (\pi -4-\log (4)) \cos \left(\frac{\pi  r}{2}\right)+8\right)\\
 - \sum_{k=1}^r(-1)^k{2r-1\choose 2k}\sum _{\ell=1}^{k-1} \frac{(-1)^\ell}{2 \ell+1} - \sum_{k=1}^r(-1)^k {2r-1\choose 2k-1}\sum _{\ell=1}^{k-1} \frac{(-1)^\ell}{2 \ell}.$$
Combining the last two terms gives
$$I=2^{r-3} (\pi -4+\log (4)) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  r}{2}\right)+2^{r-3} (\pi -4-\log (4)) \cos \left(\frac{\pi  r}{2}\right)+1\\
-\sum_{k=1}^{r}(-1)^k\left({2r-1\choose 2k}\sum_{\ell=1}^{k-1}\frac{(-1)^\ell}{2\ell+1}+{2r-1\choose 2k-1}\sum_{\ell=1}^{k-1}\frac{(-1)^\ell}{2\ell}\right),$$ where the last term is clearly a rational number.

I don't have time right now to see if this last sum has closed form. This answer is not a rigorous proof, but the formula seems to be correct. Maybe you could develop a rigorous proof starting from these insights.